# UI not responding when using google draggable marker in google map

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

In my react-native iOS app UI not responding when i drag the marker in map(Google map),in android its working perfectly.Did someone have the same issue?Please help me.Thanks in advance.

```
            <Marker 
            draggable
            coordinate={this.state.loc}
            title={"Current location"}
            onDragEnd={(e) => this.locChange(e)}
            //description={"description"}
            />
```

locChange = (e) => {

```
    console.log(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)
    this.setState({ loc: e.nativeEvent.coordinate, lng: e.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude, lat:e.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude})

}
```